# Does Realm on Xamarin support concurrent (non-nested) write transactions?

Tags: android, multithreading, xamarin, xamarin.android, realm

I'm getting an occasional Realms.RealmInvalidTransactionException exception on calls like this:

```
var realm = Realm.GetInstance;

using (var trans = realm.BeginWrite())
{
    var stopActualItem = realm.All<StopActualItemRealm>().Where(r => r.StopActualId == stopActualId).ToList().FirstOrDefault();

    if (stopActualItem == null)
    {
        stopActualItem = realm.CreateObject<StopActualItemRealm>();
    }

    // Code that updates the stopActualItem class would be here

    trans.Commit();
}
```

At the same time, code in a background thread can also be writing to the Realm database in another BeginWrite() transaction.  The exception appears to be thrown when the attempt is made to do concurrent writes.  Each thread is calling Realm.GetInstance().  Are concurrent Realm write transactions allowed or do I need to queue them?

I am using Realm v0.76.1 with Xamarin.Android

Answer (score 1):

Yes concurrent write requests are supported and on one of our internal test apps have been thrashed with dozens of threads writing non-stop.

The Xamarin product uses the same C++ core engine heavily tested by other Android users from Java.

To exolain further, there's an entire [deep dive into threading in Realm](https://realm.io/news/threading-deep-dive/) but the short version is we have MVCC with (fast) blocking on the entire DB. So at any given instant, only one thread is in the act of writing, whilst other writes are synchronised and blocking. No reads are ever blocked by writes.

It is of course possible we have a bug and would really appreciate a demo app to see if we can replicate, along with more details as to the Android environment in which this is occurring. Please [log an issue](https://github.com/realm/realm-dotnet/issues) with extra details

If you need to keep it private please email to help@realm.io.